# Could not parse the remainder: || django template

Tags: django, templates, conditional-statements

I trying to make or condition in django template and getting this error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: ' || 'default_avatar.png'' from 'userprofile.avatar || 'default_avatar.png''
```

code

```
src="/media/{{userprofile.avatar || 'default_avatar.png'}}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||` is not valid syntax either in Python or in the Django template language.

If you want to set a default for when your object is empty, use the template filter designed for that: [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#default).

```
{{ userprofile.avatar|default:'default_avatar.png' }}
```